# 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'summary'

Tags: python, scikit-learn, linear-regression

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression

lr= LinearRegression()

X=[[1.1,1.3,1.5]]
y=[[39343,46205,37731]]

lr.fit(X, y)

lr.summary()
```

---

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
 in 
----> 1 lr.summary()

AttributeError: 'LinearRegression' object has no attribute 'summary'

Comment: What's the question? From [the docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html), Linear regression has no such method.

Comment: I guess you may be confusing `sklearn` with `statsmodels`?

Comment: Hi,
my question was wrong.
I was confused b/w R's regression and python's.

actually in R we can do :  summary(model).
but in python:  statsmodels' Ordinary Least Square is the way to do it.
Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

The method `summary()`, simply does not exist under the name `lr`, if you are trying to access the coefficients you can use :

```
reg.coef_
```

other than that, you would be better off checking the docs : [sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression docs](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.get_params)

or you can instantly check what names you can access under `lr` using :

```
dir(lr)
```

or read the help docs using :

```
help(lr)
```

Comment: actually sometimes back, i have used 'summary()'

Comment: then this can only mean you're mistaking the class ```LinearRegression``` for something else. try checking  the```statsmodels``` module. hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I have this problem all the time. It's because you need to use statsmodel's Ordinary Least Square function (sm.OLS(y,x,data=data_frame)) before fitting the model. You should probably [add a constant to the x axis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30286095/do-i-need-to-add-a-constant-when-using-sm-ols) as well:

```
from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
import statsmodels.api as sm

lr= LinearRegression()

X=[[1.1,1.3,1.5]]
y=[[39343,46205,37731]]
X = sm.add_constant(X)

model = sm.OLS(y,X)
fitted_model = model.fit()
fitted_model.summary()
```

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31172107)

Answer (score 0):

I was confused b/w R's regression and python's.

and yes if u want to see the similar summary report in python then ,
statsmodels' Ordinary Least Square is the way to do it.